# Move rows to another sheet if meeting criteria

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

If the cells is equal to Disney Orlando I want to move to worksheet New or a completely new worksheet. As of now the .Rows is causing an error.

```
Sub finddisneys()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("April")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("alljobs")
Set ws3 = wb.Sheets("New")


i = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For i = z To 2 Step -1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 2) = "Disney Orlando" Then
        .Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.range("A")
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: you can't preced an argument with a `.` unless inside a `With` block.  So put `ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.range("A2")`

Comment: Also your line `
i = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` need to be `
z = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: You're missing a `Next i`.

Comment: (... and switch the whole thing to an [AutoFilter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx))

Comment: This only catches, copies and pastes one line. How do I change the destination change to roll with the for loop?

Comment: Where do you want the copied data to go? To the equivalent line on `WS3` or the next available line in `ws3` if we paste starting in row 1?

Comment: `ws1.Rows(i).Copy Destination:=ws3.Range("A" & ws3.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset (1)` will paste it in the next empty row.

Comment: @BruceWayne the next available line, but it looks like Scott's got it.

Answer (score 2):

Just need to do some "housekeeping" on the code:

```
Sub finddisneys()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet


Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("April")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("alljobs")
Set WS3 = wb.Sheets("New")


i = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).row ' Added ws1 before "Rows" for clarity
For i = z To 2 Step -1
    If ws1.Cells(i, 2) = "Disney Orlando" Then
        ws1.Rows(i).copy Destination:=WS3.Range("A") ' Added ws1, since you didn't have `With` anywhere.
    End If
Next i ' Need this to continue the loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Edit: Ah, I see Scott and Jeeped are all over it.

Comment: Since there is but a single (bad) destination, you might want to `Exit For` after meeting the first match or change the destination to a new location like the next empty row.